# Error while using rstrip in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe df with one of the column "values". It contains -

```
values
[u'12f4',u'ff45',u'tr23']
[u'125g4',u'ff145',u'trr523']
[u'12f34',u'ff2345',u'trg23a']
```

I want to remove ']' from each cell. I am using the following code -

```
df['values'] = df['values'].map(lambda x: x.rstrip(']'))
```

This gives me an error -

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: How does it work? It seems some `NaN`s are in column, so `map` return error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use [`str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
df['values'] = df['values'].str.rstrip(']')
```